# How could I toggle a class on body in Next/React/material-ui projects

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I have a project which written in Next.js and React.js. I want to implement dark-mode toggle by setting cookie, so I use `<switch>` from material-ui but I have problem, when I add class to `<body>` on toggle I receive an error which tells `document is not defined` ! and I can't add or remove class on `<body>`! also when `<switch>` is checked and I refresh the page `<switch>` doesn't keep state and change off but when it's false it keep the state!

```
    import React, { useState, } from 'react';
    import Switch from '@material-ui/core/Switch';
    import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
    import styles from './DarkMode.module.scss';
    
    const DarkMode = () => {
      const [state, setState, ] = useState({ checkedA: false, });
    
      const darkModeHandler = (event) => {
        setState({
          ...state, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked,
        });
        Cookies.set('darkMode', event.target.checked);
        document.body.classList.add('darkMode');
      };

  return (
    <div
      className={styles.root}
    >
      <Switch
        checked={state.checkedA}
        onChange={darkModeHandler}
        color="primary"
        name="checkedA"
        inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'primary checkbox', }}
      />

    </div>
  );
};
export default DarkMode;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's fix the state retain on reload. There are 2 ways of doing this.

1. using Cookies.get inside `useState`, which is not recommended.

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    checkedA: Cookies.get("darkMode") || false
  });
```

2. Using useEffect and setting the state on inital render

```
useEffect(() => {
    setState((initalState) => {
      return { ...initalState, checkedA: Cookies.get("darkMode") || false };
    });
  }, []);
```

Toggling between `darkMode` and `lightMode`

Use `toggle` method provided with classList property to acheive this.

```
const darkModeHandler = (event) => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.checked
    });
    Cookies.set("darkMode", event.target.checked);
    document.body.classList.toggle("darkMode");
  };
```

We still want to see dark mode on the inital render when `switch` is checked, so need to update `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
    setState((initalState) => {
      return { ...initalState, checkedA: Cookies.get("darkMode") || false };
    });
    if(!Cookies.get("darkMode")){
      document.body.classList.toggle("darkMode");
    }
  }, []);
```

Working example https://codesandbox.io/embed/toggle-theme-zq3pu?file=/src/App.js